# Taking back what's mine but by stealing

Tags: halal-haram, theft

Someone stole all of my money from me and I know who it is but I don't have proof because I witnessed it with my own eyes. Is it okay to take back exactly the same amount that he stole from me?Stealing back from him. He stole all of my money and it's my roommate.

Comment: Why not talk to him and ask about it, with a kind approach? Could it be a misunderstanding from your side or a mistake from his side? Did he take it secretly from your bag/wallet or from an open place like on the table, on a shelf etc. Maybe he made a mistake and thought the money was his? Or maybe he took it for something he can't tell you and will put it back as soon as he can (still wrong)? If he indeed steal it, if you talk to him kindly, he might tell you why he did it and give it back to you. If you try to take the money back without him knowing, that may make the situation worse.

Comment: He took my money secretly at around 3 am. He was going through my bag and found my wallet he took the money I saw with my own eyes but I don't know why I didn't stop him

Comment: It might be difficult to talk to your friend in a case like this, but it is better if you talk to him. Stealing is not something to be taken lightly under no circumstance (some people die of hunger/malnutrition, yet they do not steal food from others), so you need to tell him you saw him and that if he needed money that he could ask you and if you can give any you can, or not etc. Unless your friend's act is a one time mistake, and that he regrets and repents after your talk, I wouldn't feel safe to live with someone who steals from those who live with them and trust them.